# Does NFSv3 respect ZFS ACL's?

Tags: linux, freebsd, nfs, zfs, access-control-list

NFSv3 of course doesn't support ZFS ACL's, but what will happen if I have the following setup?:

```
+-----------------------------------------+            +-------------+
|           FreeBSD ZFS serv1             |    NFSv3   | Linux serv2 |
| user1:      read/write to /zfs/project1 | <--------- | user1       |
| user2: deny read/write to /zfs/project1 |            | user2       |
+-----------------------------------------+            +-------------+
```

ZFS ACL's have been set on serv1 and serv2 mounts over NFSv3.

**Question**

I assume `uers1` will be able to read/write as that is what NFSv3 world normally do.

But will `user2` be denied?

Comment: I'd try it and see. Easy to test.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ben Rockwood (solaris guru) blogged about this in greater detail:  [NFS ZFS ACL's](http://www.cuddletech.com/blog/pivot/entry.php?id=939).  The part that pertains to your question is a few sections down.

In short, it won't work.  You need to upgrade to NFSv4 (eh), or use POSIX ACL's on a different FS (boo!).

I say "eh" about NFSv4 b/c I tried to figure it out a few times & failed.  It seems to require a very homogenous environment centered around LDAP & Kerberos, which is actually great from a security standpoint, but a bummer if you just want to test stuff & don't have all those things.  Hopefully you'll have better luck.

Comment: what doesn't work? I know I can't manage ACL's over NFSv3, but the permissions have already been set on the server. Will `user2` be denied or given access?

Comment: `user2` will be denied, possibly even `user1`, depending on what the POSIX permissions are.  All `serv2` will see are the POSIX permissions; it will not see the ZFS ACL's at all.

Comment: I *think* that blog post is now here: [Solaris ACL’s Today](http://cuddletech.com/?p=459).  (The blog was redesigned at some point and the old URLs don't appear to have been preserved.)